# Allow cross domain request to jersey web services

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jersey, cross-domain

Facing issue related to allowing cross domain requests in jersey.
I tried to implement `com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponseFilters`, but not able to configure it.

Getting exception, when try to send the request from browser.

> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke SEVERE:
>   Servlet.service() for servlet [JAX-RS Servlet] in context with path
>   [/crawlerweb] threw exception [Servlet execution threw an exception]
>   with root cause java.lang.AbstractMethodError:
>   javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder.uri(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljavax/ws/rs/core/UriBuilder;
>   at javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder.fromUri(UriBuilder.java:119) at
>   com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.j‌​ava:662)

Comment: adding e contents from comment. Most user don't read comments , can comments get deleted on SO. So always consider [editing] question with adequent information by clicking edit

Comment: Don't mix Jersey 1.x and Jersey 2.x or JAX-RS 1.x and JAX-RS 2.x dependencies. This is the cause of your problem. Pick one version, and stick to it. Get rid of eveything else

Comment: Thanks for reply, I try

Answer (score 0):

You must implement support for CORS in your jersey service.
For cross domain request, browser first sends a preflight httprequest with OPTIONS method.
Then your server must return certain CORS headers in response.

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin :*
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST
```

Browsers checks for those headers if they are present then it makes the real httprequest that you want.

You can try this

```
return Response.ok() 
        .entity(podcastById, detailed ? new Annotation[]{PodcastDetailedView.Factory.get()} : new Annotation[0])
        .header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
        .header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST")
        .allow("OPTIONS").build();
```